# Why a declared and filled mwSize saves the day when a constant doesn't

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, fortran, mex, intel-fortran

I have this subroutine :

```
    subroutine FotranDgemmMatrixMultiplication(A, B, C, m, n, p, mkl)
        integer m, n, p
        real*8 mkl
        real*8 A(m,n), B(n,p), C(m,p)
        if (mkl .ne. 1) then
            C = matmul(A,B)
        else
            C = matmul(B,A)
        endif
    end
```

that I use in a mex gateway file as follows :

```
#include <fintrf.h>
C     The gateway routine
    subroutine mexFunction(nlhs, plhs, nrhs, prhs)

    implicit none
    mwPointer mxGetM, mxGetN, mxIsNumeric, mxIsLogical
    mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
    mwPointer plhs(*), prhs(*)
    mwPointer A_pr, B_pr, C_pr, mkl_pr
    mwPointer mxGetPr
    integer nlhs, nrhs
    real*8, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: x, y, z
    real*8 mkl
    mwSize m, n, p, q, r, s
    mwSize size1, size2, size3

C     Check for proper number of arguments. 
    if (nrhs .ne. 3) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Three inputs required.')
    elseif (nlhs .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('One output required.')
    endif

C     Check to see both inputs are numeric.
    if (mxIsNumeric(prhs(1)) .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #1 is not a numeric array.')
    elseif (mxIsNumeric(prhs(2)) .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #2 is not a numeric array.')
    elseif (mxIsNumeric(prhs(3)) .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #3 is not a numeric array.')
    endif

C     Get the size of the input matrix #1.
    m = mxGetM(prhs(1))
    n = mxGetN(prhs(1))

C     Get the size of the input matrix #2.
    p = mxGetM(prhs(2))
    q = mxGetN(prhs(2))

C     Check that the sizes are compatible for a matrix product
    if (n .ne. p) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('nbcol1 should be equal to nbrow2.')
    endif

    size1 = m*n
    size2 = p*q

C     Check that the input #3 is a scalar
    r = mxGetM(prhs(3))
    s = mxGetN(prhs(3))
    if(r .ne. 1 .or. s .ne. 1) then
        call mexErrMsgTxt('Input #3 is not a scalar.')
    endif

C     Create matrix for the return argument.
    plhs(1) = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m, q, 0)
    A_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(1))
    B_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(2))
    mkl_pr = mxGetPr(prhs(3))
    C_pr = mxGetPr(plhs(1))

    allocate( x(m,n), y(p,q), z(m,q) )

C     Load the data into Fortran arrays.
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(A_pr, x, size1)
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(B_pr, y, size2)
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(mkl_pr, mkl, 1) ! suspicious line

C     Call the computational subroutine.
    call FotranDgemmMatrixMultiplication(x, y, z, m, n, q, mkl) ! crash here

C     Load the output into a MATLAB array.
    size3 = m*q
    call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(z, C_pr, size3)

    !deallocate(x,y,z)

    return
    end
```

that executes as intended in debug but that crashes in release, the crash occuring at line :

```
    call FotranDgemmMatrixMultiplication(x, y, z, m, n, q, mkl)
```

If I add a `mwSize sizeOne` with `sizeOne = 1` and replace the suspicious line (see the code) with :

```
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(mkl_pr, mkl, sizeOne)
```

then the crash doesn't occur anymore. I don't understand what is happening as in `x64` the "type" `mwSize` is defined (in `fintrf.h`) as `mwpointer` which itself is defined as `integer*4`, which should treat the "constant" `1` correctly normally.

Comment: How is mwSize declared in the include file? I guess it is 64 bit and the subroutine is compiled with 64 bit integers.

Comment: It is declared as I wrote in my question. The compilation options are `/nologo /O2 /fpp /I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\extern\include" /I"%IFORT_COMPILER19%mkl\include" /DMATLAB_MEX_FILE /names:uppercase /module:"x64\Release\\" /object:"x64\Release\\" /Fd"x64\Release\vc150.pdb" /libs:dll /threads /c /extfor:F /Qlocation,link,"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64" /Qm64`

Comment: It is hard to believe that a pointer would be 4 bytes in 64bit compilation.

Comment: Have a look at the `finrtf.h` then.

Comment: It may be a wrong header for your compilation then. /Qm64 means 64 bit pointers. Or a wrong compilation flag and a correct header.

Comment: The compilation flags are those from my visual studio intel fortran dll project, release configuration.

Comment: Yes, but they may not be the right ones for mex.

Comment: Yes, I know, will see that with the intel guys, the matlab ones never answering on their forum.

Comment: OK, I thought `/Qm64` that also made the compiler understand integer and real constant litterals as x64 litterals, allowing me to write `1` instead of `1_8` for instance. I was wrong.